# Why the below code throws error When function name Bar is already defined?

Tags: javascript

```
    var Foo = function Bar() {
               return 7;
    };
    typeof Bar();
```

// Uncaught ReferenceError: Bar is not defined

Comment: The name given in a `function` expression like that is not made part of the local namespace.

Comment: You *can* access `Bar()` **inside** `Bar()`, though.